# React Native: react-native-gesture-handler: seems like using an old api after yarn

Tags: react-native, react-native-gesture-handler

I reinstalled all my node_modules in my react-native project using yarn (Delete node_modules and run yarn). After it finished I've started my app and there heappens to pop up this warning:

> [react-native-gesture-handler] Seems like you're using an old API with
> gesture components, check out new Gestures system!

And then it lists a lot of react-native elements (I think) like this:

```
PanGestureHandler@http://IP/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.legosocialmedia&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:133321:38
PanGestureHandler@http://IP/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.legosocialmedia&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:132628:34
RCTView
View
AnimatedComponent@http://IP/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.legosocialmedia&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:68721:38
AnimatedComponentWrapper
RCTView
View
Card@http://IP/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.legosocialmedia&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:131894:36
CardContainer@http://IP/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.legosocialmedia&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:131451:34
RNSScreen

And so on....
```

I tried reinstalling react-native-gesture-handler (**yarn romove react-native-gesture-handler** and **yarn add react-native-gesture-handler**), but that didn't change anything.

Comment: First, delete your `yarn.lock` file, then try `yarn add react-native-gesture-handler@latest`. See what that gets you.

Comment: I think thats going to make impossible to run yarn install to install the dependencies, right?

Comment: The yarn.lock should be regenerated after reinstalling all your packages.

Comment: @AleksandarZoric Do I have to reinstall all the packages manually?

Comment: Run yarn install, or just yarn.
Or NPM install or just NPM i, this will install all packages for you. 


Yarn.lock is a generated file that yarn uses to know what versions of each dependency are installed so it can get those exact versions again when you run yarn install on a new machine.

The lock file is updated in its entirety on any change to dependencies, i.e. when you run a yarn command.

Comment: When starting, my metro gives me the error:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, watch 'E:\Dokumente\GitHub\Project\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android\build\kotlin\compileDebugKotlin\caches-jvm'
In the terminal, where I ran yarn android, the react-native-gesture-handler: compile-debug-kotlin task tells me that some runtime jar-files haven't got the same version and a lot of constructors or other code is deprecated in Java

Comment: I'm also getting the "Deprecated in Java"-Warning on Task :react-native-screens:compileDebugKotlin and at the end of the build, I get the Warning "Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings"

Comment: `yarn.lock` is auto-generated after running `yarn`. It tells yarn which version of libraries listed in the `package.json` to install on subsequent installs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The new version, of **react-native-gesture-handler** send warning if you use an old API version, but also if one of your package/library use it.

To disable the warning, you can ignore logs.

in your app.js / app.tsx

```
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';

LogBox.ignoreLogs([
  "[react-native-gesture-handler] Seems like you\'re using an old API with gesture components, check out new Gestures system!",
]);
```

[Here you have the explanation](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/pull/1817)

**UPDATE**

This is now fix since : `react-native-gesture-handler": "2.1.1"`

Comment: Put it in your app.js:

`
import React from "react"
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";

 const App: () => Node = () => {

   LogBox.ignoreLogs([
    "[react-native-gesture-handler] Seems like you\'re using an old API with gesture components, check out new Gestures system!",
  ]);

  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView>
      <YourCode/>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
};
`

Comment: What do I need the GestureHandlerRootView for?

Comment: It's maybe, one of the package in your node modules need it.

Comment: That's not a solution, it is only to hide the issue. With the same success it is possible to hide all warnings, that at some point can result in errors.

Comment: i had set ignoreAllLog but still error

Answer (score 2):

This error is ridiculous :D
force the 2.1.1 version. and you won't see that annoying error again:

"react-native-gesture-handler": "2.1.1",

Comment: In which file do I have to put this?

Comment: @JaRoMaster in `package.json`

Comment: I'm running 2.3 and I still see that message...

Answer (score 1):

it may causes by `react-navigation` package if so use `@react-navigation/native-stack` instead of `@react-navigation/stack` from this [link](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/1831#issuecomment-1015272477)

Answer (score 1):

This way worked for me.
Install

```
npm i react-native-gesture-handler@2.1.1
```

or install the version based on what expo has mentioned when starting the server (for eg : expected version is 2.1.1)

then close the server and open again by resetting cache

```
expo r -c
```

Comment: I'm not working with expo...

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem. I kept getting this warning!. The solution provided below helps ignore the warning, but is not a root solution. and it may make your app bigger in size. Any other solutions

````
import { LogBox } from 'react-native;
   LogBox.ignoreLogs([
  "[react-native-gesture-handler] Seems like you\'re using an old API with gesture components, check out new Gestures system!",
]);```
````

Answer (score 0):

**React native CLI**

just use this version

```
npm i react-native-gesture-handler@2.1.1
```

package.json

```
"react-native": "0.66.1",

"react-native-reanimated": "^2.4.1",

"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",

"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

Actually, the warning is shows if you updated the `react-native-gesture-handler` to the latest version. You can ignore the warning by adding the following code.

```
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';

LogBox.ignoreLogs([
  "[react-native-gesture-handler] Seems like you\'re using an old API with gesture components, check out new Gestures system!",
]);
```

Solution 2:

You can downgrade the `react-native-gesture-handler` to the old version using the following command. It will fix the error.

```
yarn add react-native-gesture-handler@2.1.1
```