# Invariant Violation: Module `AppRegistry` is not a registered callable module (calling `runApplication`). and etc

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am making a project using `react-native`, when I added drawer navigation it started giving me an error as:

> Invariant Violation: Module `AppRegistry` is not a registered callable module (calling `runApplication`). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
> This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., `js` engine: `hermes`

so when I search for the solution I came across this answer https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/846#issuecomment-943267584 - But when I followed the procedure as given in this link it started giving me two error - **Error: Reanimated 2 failed to create a worklet, maybe you forgot to add Reanimated's babel plugin?, js engine: hermes** and also the above error. I am using react-native 0.67. please help if you can.

Comment: Can you try removing the cache of the whole project and try again? You can start with this command: yarn start --reset-cache . if it doesn't work you can try these steps: rm -rf ./node_modules
yarn
cd ios
pod deintegrate
pod install
yarn start --reset-cache

Comment: I haven't use yarn in my project all the packages are downloaded using npm

Comment: It's okay, use npm instead of yarn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to add this line in your babel.config.js file; Then run again, may be helps you

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
      "react-native-reanimated/plugin"
    ]

};
```

Comment: It worked, but now it is giving a warning as "[react-native-gesture-handler] Seems like you're using an old API with gesture components, check out new Gestures system!" so is there any way to resolve this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70756058/react-native-react-native-gesture-handler-seems-like-using-an-old-api-after-ya

Comment: after adding above lines it shows error: index.js: Cannot find module 'react-native-reanimated/plugin'

Answer (score 0):

After adding the `react-native-reanimated` to your project

Add Reanimated's Babel plugin to your `babel.config.js`:

```
  module. Exports = {
    presets: [
      ...
     ],
    plugins: [
     ...
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
    ],
   };
```

- `yarn start --reset-cache`
- `npm start -- --reset-cache`
- `expo start -c`

Comment: after adding above lines it shows error: index.js: Cannot find module 'react-native-reanimated/plugin'

Answer (score 0):

for me, it seems that the new react native version 0.70 is not compatible with react native navigation package,
after removing the navigation package, and clearing the cache the code works!

```
yarn remove @react-native-navigation

yarn start --reset-cache
```